# Trim decimal to 2 decimal places except if decimal has more than 2 decimal places

Tags: c#, winforms, decimal

So this is a bit of a picky question. I have looked around for similar questions, but couldn't find one that specifically answers my question.

I'm making a winforms app that gets data from, among other things, numeric updowns and places them in Word docvariables. The numeric updowns have a precision of 4 decimal places, because there are some prices like €0,0125 for example printing contracts. But other prices will get saved as for example €12,5000. I currently fix the numbers with 2 decimal places like this:

```
string value = type.GetValue().ToString().Trim(new char[] { '\'' });
//Changes commas for European standard and removes the excess zeros after the comma.
if (type.GetType().ToString().EndsWith("Decimal"))
{
    string s;
    string sep = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
    if (sep == ".")
        s = double.Parse(value).ToString("n2").Replace('.', ',');

    else
        s = double.Parse(value).ToString("n2");

    wordDoc.Variables[type.GetName()].Value = s;
}
else
    wordDoc.Variables[type.GetName()].Value = value;
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to detect when a decimal shouldn't get trimmed. I don't necessarily need code examples, if someone just could send me on the right track, that would be a major help.

NB: Changing the precision of the numeric up downs isn't really an option since they get created dynamically by a method.

Comment: Can you give some examples of how you want it to behave? It is not clear what result you want

Comment: When a decimal is `12,5000`, I want it to show `12,50`. And when it's `0,125` or `0,1250`, I need it to show `0,125`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a [custom format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx) - `#,##0.00##` will show a minimum of 2 d.p. and a maximum of 4 d.p.

```
decimal x = 12.50000m;
decimal y = 0.0125m;

string sx = x.ToString("#,##0.00##"); // "12.50"
string sy = y.ToString("#,##0.00##"); // "0.125"
```

If you want a comma decimal separator, then either use an appropriate `CultureInfo` or create a `NumberFormatInfo` with the correct properties:

```
var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo
{
    NumberDecimalSeparator = ",",
    NumberGroupSeparator = ".",
};

string s = 1234.56m.ToString("#,##0.00##", nfi); // "1.234,56"
```

Comment: Wow, I really need to learn about custom format strings. Thanks a bunch!